# Trailing Sum Calculation using pre-defined kernel (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, function, sum, kernel

Table Z:
[image]

**Goal**: Calculating a 12-point trailing sum for any date point looking upward in the table, e.g. 20-May-2016 must display the sum of the shaded area (0.1768).

So far:

```
[rows, columns] = size(Z);
onesVector = ones(rows, 1);
kernel12t = [0;0;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1]; % Kernel that computes
% the trailing 12 values
trailingSum12t = zeros(rows, columns);
for col = 4 : columns
    thisColumn = Z{:, col}; % Extract all rows from this column.
    cellSum12t = conv(onesVector, kernel12t, 'same');
    valuesSum12t = conv(thisColumn, kernel12t, 'same');
    trailingSum12t(:, col) = valuesSum12t;
end
```

The outcome of "*trailingSum12t*" is displayed below. However, the highlighted cell shouldn't be 0.1760 but 0.1768. Strangely I find the correct sum of the 12-point trailing kernel (0.1768) in a cell (row 8) where it shouldn't be. 
[image]

Another issue is found in "*cellSum12t*" (see below): rows 551-554 should contain 12's! 
[image]

The upper part of "*cellSum12t*" looks perfect though (see below):

[image]

Comment: Can you post some actual [mcve]? In this case I also mean a minimum table. Its hard to test code using screenshots of data

Comment: what do you mean by minimum table? No need to determine min etc. in my context since the only issue is that my trailing sum starts at the wrong cell.
N.b. This is the maximum of information I can upload (no .mat files etc.): my code & function, the data it refers to (table Z) as well as the outcome of my code.

Comment: Minimal table, sorry. Read the link I posted. You can invent a table, no need to be the real one. We want to copy paste and test your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adjust zeros in kernel to n - 1 where n = (trailing sum window)

```
kernel12t = [0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1];
```